# /bin/sh: 1: not found make: *** [manuscript.mk:140: compose] Error 127

Tags: makefile

I used `FILES:=$(wildcard *_*_*_*/*.docx)` to list all docx files in the folders, but I got this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: not found
make: *** [manuscript.mk:140: compose] Error 127.
```

All files are instead listed before once.

Thanks!

Comment: We can't help because you haven't shown us enough info.  There is nothing wrong with the wildcard function you provided, and that's all we can see.  Please cut and paste the make rule that is at `manuscript.mk` line, and also please show not just the error message but also the text before it that shows what command make invoked.

Comment: I'll just say up front: you cannot use files or paths containing whitespace with make.  Being a POSIX-based tool it's not designed to work with them as they're legal, but rare, on POSIX systems which were command-line based (no GUI interface) when make was created.  So, if the `*_*_*_*` or the `*.docx` matches directories or files containing whitespace you will have problems.